# How do we import a docker data volume in Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, volumes

I need to copy docker's data volume from Mac to Windows. I've already got the `tgz` file with volume from Mac, then I create an `alpine` container, and check `/var/lib/docker` folder on Windows 10 as I did it on Mac.

What I see is that `/var/lib` folder is empty on my Windows 10.

[image]

How could I access the folder with volumes on Windows to copy mine there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can add a volume to Windows docker manually:

First step is to create the volume with the same name as you have in your `tar` backup file: `docker volume create myvolume`

Next, you need to run a simple image and mount there docker volumes folder and some folder on this image. You also need to mount some windows folder with a folder in your container to be able to copy your image to container.

`docker run --rm -it -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/volumes -v c:/temp:/windows alpine`

- `-v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/volumes` - mounts a docker's volumes folder to a folder in your container
- `c:/temp:/windows` - mounts a `c:/temp` folder on your windows with a folder `windows` in your container

All you need to do after is just copy your volume inside a container from `windows` to `volumes` `cp /windows/myvolume /volumes -r`

For Docker on Windows to make folder sharing work don't forget to enable shared drive in settings
[image]